# React/Redux call multiple actions in sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Ok, so I have a container that calls the function (action creator) **boardClicked**. If the correct item is clicked, then that item's "found" property gets updated in state.characters array. Now, if this is true, I also need to run a second action **CHARACTER_ACTIVATED** that will update other components by setting the activeCharacter to the very next item in the array. However, I can't figure out how to call another action (theoretically, I would want it to take place in reducer_characters inside the **if (character.id === action.payload.id && character.id === action.payload.activeCharacter)** condition. However, I cant dispatch an action from here. Very stumped here as to best way to go about this. Basically, I want to get the index of the current active character, find the next item in the array, and pass that like **selectCharacter(nextCharacter)**. Any direction much appreciated.

**actions/index.js**

```
    export function selectCharacter(character) {
        // Action creator; needs to return an action (an object with a type property)
        return {
            type: 'CHARACTER_ACTIVATED',
            payload: character
        };
    }

    export function boardClicked(event, activeCharacter) {
        return {
            type: 'BOARD_CLICKED',
            payload: {
                "id": event.target.id,
                "activeCharacter": activeCharacter.id
            }
        };
    }
```

**reducers/reducer_characters.js**

```
const characters = [
    { 
        id: '_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell',
        name: 'Stringer Bell', 
        'avatar': 'img/1.jpg',
        found: false,
    },
    { 
        id: '_x30_2-A-Kenard',
        name: 'Kenard',
        'avatar': 'img/2.jpg',
        found: false
    },
    ...
];

export default function(state = characters, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'BOARD_CLICKED':
      return state.map((character) => {  // map over the characters, returning a new array
        if (character.id === action.payload.id && character.id === action.payload.activeCharacter) { // if character id matches action id, change that character 
          return {
            ... character,
            found: !character.found 
          }

        } else { // if the id doesn't match, return the original character
          return character
        }
      });
    default:
      return state; 
  }
}
```

**reducers/reducer_characters.js**

```
export default function(state =  { id: '_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell', name: 'Stringer Bell', avatar: 'img/1.jpg', found: false }, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CHARACTER_ACTIVATED':
            return action.payload;
    }

    return state;
}
```

**containers/board.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SVGInline from "react-svg-inline";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { boardClicked, selectCharacter } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Board extends Component {

    render() {
        return (        
            <div id="board" onClick={(event) => this.props.boardClicked(event, this.props.activeCharacter)}>
                <SVGInline svg={'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) --><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2489.5 1872.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2489.5 1872.7;" xml:space="preserve"><image style="overflow:visible;" width="2500" height="1928" id="Illustration_1_" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C0534C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -5.5 -55)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="164" id="_x30_1-B-RussellStringerBell" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C0534D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 722.5 498)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="164" id="_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C05342.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 722.5 498)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="102" height="144" id="_x30_2-B-Kenard" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C05343.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1316.5 681)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="102" height="151" id="_x30_2-A-Kenard" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C05344.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1316.5 674)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="86" height="144" id="_x30_3-B-MarloStanfield" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C05341.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 564.5 1086)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="86" height="144" id="_x30_3-A-MarloStanfield" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C05340.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 564.5 1086)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="79" height="132" id="_x30_4-B-CalvinCheeseWagstaff" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C0535F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -3.5 1368)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="79" height="132" id="_x30_4-A-CalvinCheeseWagstaff" xlink:href="img/2A6DA3D578C0535A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -3.5 1368)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="138" height="207" id="_x30_5-B-MauriceLevy" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0997.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 594.5 1507)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="138" height="207" id="_x30_5-A-MauriceLevy" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0989.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 594.5 1507)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="100" height="165" id="_x30_6-B-SpirosVondasVondopoulos" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC098A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 283.5 1206)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="100" height="165" id="_x30_6-A-SpirosVondasVondopoulos" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC098B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 283.5 1206)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="195" id="_x30_7-B-The_Greek" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC098F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 186.5 1185)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="195" id="_x30_7-A-The_Greek" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0988.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 186.5 1185)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="171" height="180" id="_x30_8-B-PropositionJoe" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0986.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 521.5 377)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="174" height="181" id="_x30_8-A-PropositionJoe" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0987.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 521.5 376)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="140" height="161" id="_x30_9-B-BriannaBarksdale" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09B3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1136.5 417)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="149" height="175" id="_x30_9-A-BriannaBarksdale" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09B4.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1127.5 403)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="186" id="_x31_0-B-DeLondaBrice" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09AA.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 247.5 1055)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="186" id="_x31_0-A-DeLondaBrice" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09A6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 247.5 1055)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="186" height="376" id="_x31_1-B-JayLandsman" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09A7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1983.5 727)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="186" height="376" id="_x31_1-A-JayLandsman" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09DC.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1983.5 727)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="109" height="247" id="_x31_2-B-AvonBarksdale" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09DD.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 444.5 1150)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="109" height="247" id="_x31_2-A-AvonBarksdale" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09DE.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 444.5 1150)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="190" id="_x31_3-B-BeadieRussell" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09E3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1577.5 1485)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="133" height="197" id="_x31_3-A-BeadieRussell" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09E4.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1569.5 1478)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="139" height="350" id="_x31_4-B-WilliamRawls" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09E5.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1688.5 1409)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="139" height="351" id="_x31_4-A-WilliamRawls" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09E7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1688.5 1408)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="99" height="194" id="_x31_5-B-NickSobotka" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09FD.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 309.5 1679)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="99" height="194" id="_x31_5-A-NickSobotka" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09C0.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 309.5 1679)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="309" id="_x31_6-B-ClarenceRoyce" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09C6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1179.5 1548)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="324" id="_x31_6-A-ClarenceRoyce" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09CE.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1179.5 1533)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="152" height="217" id="_x31_7-B-TommyCarcetti" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09CA.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2211.5 1656)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="154" height="219" id="_x31_7-A-TommyCarcetti" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09CB.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2209.5 1654)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="152" id="_x31_8-B-ThomasKlebanow" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09D0.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1911.5 1721)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="127" height="153" id="_x31_8-A-ThomasKlebanow" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09D1.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1911.5 1720)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="137" height="153" id="_x31_9_x5F_B-ScottTempleton" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09D2.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1817.5 1720)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="137" height="153" id="_x31_9_x5F_A-ScottTempleton" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC09D3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1817.5 1720)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="108" height="193" id="_x32_0-B-ClayDavis" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A2B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1583.5 365)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="108" height="193" id="_x32_0-A-ClayDavis" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A25.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1583.5 365)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="236" id="_x32_1-B-ChrisPartlow" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A39.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 407.5 882)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="236" id="_x32_1-A-ChrisPartlow" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A3A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 407.5 882)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="145" id="_x32_2-B-SnoopPearson" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A3B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2009.5 274)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="145" id="_x32_2-A-SnoopPearson" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A38.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2009.5 274)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="66" height="107" id="_x32_3-B-RolandPryzbylewski" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A35.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 152.5 1472)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="66" height="107" id="_x32_3-A-RolandPryzbylewski" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A34.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 152.5 1472)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="199" id="_x32_4-B-BodieBroadus" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A4F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 886.5 1143)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="199" id="_x32_4-A-BodieBroadus" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A28.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 886.5 1143)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="67" height="140" id="_x32_5-B-Wallace" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A16.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1365.5 475)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="67" height="140" id="_x32_5-A-Wallace" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A11.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1365.5 475)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="171" height="248" id="_x32_6-B-WilliamBunkMoreland" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A12.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1945.5 1510)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="171" height="248" id="_x32_6-A-WilliamBunkMoreland" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A13.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1945.5 1510)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="292" id="_x32_7-B-DukieWeems" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A07.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1476.5 986)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="292" id="_x32_7-A-DukieWeems" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A0D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1476.5 986)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="291" id="_x32_8-B-RandyWagstaff" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A0F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1418.5 921)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="291" id="_x32_8-A-RandyWagstaff" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A0C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1418.5 921)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="246" id="_x32_9-B-MichaelLee" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A74.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1275.5 941)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="246" id="_x32_9-A-MichaelLee" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A75.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1275.5 941)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="223" id="_x33_0-B-NamondBrice" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A6E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1336.5 910)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="223" id="_x33_0-A-NamondBrice" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A10.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1336.5 910)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="97" height="248" id="_x33_1-B-FrankSobotka" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A1C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1783.5 295)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="97" height="248" id="_x33_1-A-FrankSobotka" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A04.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1783.5 295)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="90" height="248" id="_x33_2-B-RhondaPearlman" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A05.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1949.5 108)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="90" height="248" id="_x33_2-A-RhondaPearlman" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A02.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1949.5 108)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="117" height="159" id="_x33_3-B-EllisCarver" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A03.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1957.5 1103)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="117" height="159" id="_x33_3-A-EllisCarver" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A00.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1957.5 1103)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="111" height="192" id="_x33_4-B-ThomasHercHauk" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A01.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1869.5 1086)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="111" height="192" id="_x33_4-A-ThomasHercHauk" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A2A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1869.5 1086)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="154" id="_x33_5-B-AugustusHaynes" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A20.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2113.5 1416)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="154" id="_x33_5-A-AugustusHaynes" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A29.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2113.5 1416)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="184" id="_x33_6-B-LesterFreamon" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF8.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1652.5 379)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="184" id="_x33_6-A-LesterFreamon" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF9.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1652.5 379)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="136" height="200" id="_x33_7-B-CedricDaniels" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AFE.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2256.5 1335)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="136" height="200" id="_x33_7-A-CedricDaniels" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AFF.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2256.5 1335)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="202" id="_x33_8-B-SlimCharles" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AFC.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1915.5 870)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="202" id="_x33_8-A-SlimCharles" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF4.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1915.5 870)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="133" height="159" id="_x33_9-B-HowardBunnyColvin" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1044.5 1714)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="133" height="159" id="_x33_9-A-HowardBunnyColvin" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1044.5 1714)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="194" height="280" id="_x34_0-B-D_x27_AngeloBarksdale" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC8.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 809.5 554)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="194" height="280" id="_x34_0-A-D_x27_AngeloBarksdale" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0ACE.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 809.5 554)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="330" id="_x34_1-B-RolandWee-BayBrice" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC5.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 600.5 828)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="330" id="_x34_1-A-RolandWee-BayBrice" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 600.5 828)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="211" id="_x34_2-B-DennisCuttyWise" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1022.5 242)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="211" id="_x34_2-A-DennisCuttyWise" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC0.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1022.5 242)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="264" id="_x34_3-B-KimaGreggs" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC1.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1968.5 540)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="264" id="_x34_3-A-KimaGreggs" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC2.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1968.5 540)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="161" id="_x34_4-B-ReginaldBubblesCousins" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 4.5 1597)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="161" id="_x34_4-A-ReginaldBubblesCousins" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC4.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 4.5 1597)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="365" id="_x34_5-B-BrotherMouzone" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0A9F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1596.5 831)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="365" id="_x34_5-A-BrotherMouzone" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA1.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1596.5 831)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="144" height="283" id="_x34_6-B-JimmyMcNulty" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA2.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 904.5 527)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="144" height="283" id="_x34_6-A-JimmyMcNulty" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 904.5 527)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="185" id="_x34_7-B-OmarLittle" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA4.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1283.5 1103)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="185" id="_x34_7-A-OmarLittle" xlink:href="img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1283.5 1103)"></image></svg>'} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.characters.map((character) => {
            // if the character is located correctly
            if(character.found === true) {
                // hide the overlay
                document.getElementById(character.id).style.display = 'none';
            }   
        });
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        characters: state.characters,
        activeCharacter: state.activeCharacter
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // Whenever selectCharacter is called, the result should be passed to all reducers
    return bindActionCreators({ boardClicked: boardClicked, selectCharacter: selectCharacter }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

**containers/active-character.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ActiveCharacter extends Component {
    render() {      
        return (
            <div className="active-box">
                <div className="active-image">
                    <img src={this.props.character.avatar} />
                </div>
                <div className="active-name">
                    {this.props.character.name}
                </div>  
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        character: state.activeCharacter    
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ActiveCharacter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT try to dispatch an action inside of a reducer!**  Reducers should only return a new state value based on the given action.

There's a few ways you could approach this.  The couple easiest ways would involve use of the `redux-thunk` middleware, and writing a function that checks the current state.  One approach would be dispatch the first action, call `getState()` in the thunk after the dispatch is completed, find the item index, and dispatch the second action.  Another approach would be to do whatever index checking is needed first, then dispatch one action containing all the information needed to update the various parts of the state.